# How can I create a rag chain with langchain using a retriever when having multiple inputs?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, langchain, large-language-model

I'm having some issues trying to understand how to use the "|" pipe symbol in langchain when declaring a chain.

```
prompt_template = """
  Respond based only on the following context:
  {context}

As a seasoned expert tasked with optimizing a given project, your expertise is crucial 
in addressing its challenges and seizing opportunities.

Issues and Opportunities:
{issues_and_opportunities}

Business Goals:
{business_goals}

Project Description:
{description}

Please furnish a comprehensive response in JSON format, covering the following 
components:

1. Proposed Solution:
 - Articulate a detailed plan to overcome identified challenges and capitalize on 
opportunities.

2. Technological Details:
 - Conduct an in-depth analysis of the technologies earmarked for this project.
 - Specify programming languages, frameworks, and platforms to be employed.
 - Example: Python, Azure, Pytorch, Tensorflow, AWS, Openai, LLM...

 Example Output (in JSON format):
{{

 "solution": "Your detailed solution goes here",
 "technologies": ["Technology 1", "Technology 2", ...],
 }}
"""

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(prompt_template)
```

Then I build my retrieval

```
retriever = vectordb.as_retriever()
```

and my llm

```
llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
    api_key=openai_api_key,
    api_version=openai_api_version,
    azure_endpoint=openai_api_base,
    model=llm_model)
```

Then I add my outputparser

```
from langchain.output_parsers import ResponseSchema, StructuredOutputParser
from langchain.callbacks import get_openai_callback

solution_schema = ResponseSchema(name="solution", description="as given")
technologies_schema = ResponseSchema(name="technologies", description="as given")

response_schemas = [solution_schema,
                    technologies_schema]

output_parser = StructuredOutputParser.from_response_schemas(response_schemas)
```

and finally when I tried to put all this together using a chain I fail miserably

```
rag_chain = (
    {"context": retriever, "issues_and_opportunities": RunnablePassthrough(), "business_goals": RunnablePassthrough(), "description": RunnablePassthrough()}
    | prompt
    | llm
    | output_parser
)

rag_chain.invoke(issues_and_opportunities, business_goals, description)
```

Getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-3a4e499badd2> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 rag_chain.invoke(issues_and_opportunities, business_goals, description)

TypeError: RunnableSequence.invoke() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Langchain documentation](https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/interface#invoke), you should call `invoke()` on a dictionary.

So, assuming that your variables `issues_and_opportunities, business_goals, description` are strings defined in your code, this should work:

```
issues_and_opportunities = "Launching a rocket in space is hard, but spectacular."
business_goals = "Get investors."
description = "I want to create a company like SpaceX."

rag_chain.invoke({
    "issues_and_opportunities": issues_and_opportunities,
    "business_goals": business_goals,
    "description": description,
})
```

Comment: yeah, that's simple, but what happens if you want to add a retrieval?

rag_chain = {"context": itemgetter("description") | retriever,
            "issues_and_opportunities": itemgetter("issues_and_opportunities"),
            "business_goals": itemgetter("business_goals"),
            "description": itemgetter("description")} | prompt| llm | output_parser

This worked... but I really don't understand why I'm adding "description" in the context... and with this you cant change the chain_type

Comment: @JuanCruzAlricCortabarria in general, the retriever searches the relevant information in some document/database/internet and returns this information. To get this relevant information, you have to _search_ for something, hence you have to provide the description to the retriever. Similarly to Google search, you have to write something in the search bar to get the relevant information, otherwise Google cannot guess what you are looking for.